# High Frequency Oscillator

Tags: rf, communication, oscillator, radio, transmitter

I have been experimenting with the BiPolar Transistor transmitter circuits. They worked well on the 88 - 100 MHZ Range. I am now looking to increase the frequency to about 1-2 GHZ. I cant find a capacitor small enough for this freq but the coil could be winded smaller though.

I would like to know if this can be done by the use of transistors or if other Techniques are available for creating the carrier wave of 1-2 GHZ. Lastly, is there any IC's that are capable of generating this 2ghz oscillation? I have not come across any or maybe my searching was bad. Hope to hear from you guys. Thanks. [image]
![BJT Transmitter] http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/Spy%20Circuits/images/KolibriCct.gif

Comment: Please use a controlled-frequency oscillator, so you don't jam the GPS frequencies.

Comment: I am not an Electronics Expert. In my little experience, I noticed the following: When the frequency range is around 2GHz, I don't think many ICs/Transistor are available which just serves the purpose of an Oscillator. They are made for special purposes, short range communication, most of the ICs I came across are for digital signal transmission (made for specific protocols like Bluetooth, GPS etc). And yes, types of antenna becomes a matter at this frequency, I didn't see any of these circuits to use insulated Wire as Antennas. There are many when the range comes down to 1GHz. e.g. UPC1651

Answer (score 1):

To go from 100MHz to 2GHz, you are not so much 'increasing the frequency' as 'going to a new frequency band'.

There are plenty of components available for this range, though they tend to be surface mount, and in small packages. While doing design in the 3GHz ballpark, we routinely used 0603 components, though mainly moved to 0402 with the occasional 0201 to do 6GHz. You need either young eyes, very strong reading glasses, or an assembly microscope to work on those.

'Generating oscillation'. That sounds like a VCO, try using that and 2GHz in your search terms. It depends how much you want to make, and what to buy. Look at MiniCircuits for VCOs and amplifiers. Look at Analog Devices for whole synthesisers that you can program over SPI. But going those ways rather defeats the object of mucking about with small components and BFR93s.